# How does a WCF channel work?

Tags: wcf

I think I'm missing something conceptual and fundamental about WCF channels. I get how there's a channel stack of protocols on either side going from the top level TCP or HTTP down to the wire-level transport protocol.

What I don't get is what it means to "open" a channel and how that channel stays "open" and how that channel is "faulted".

What is happening on the client and service that makes a channel "open"? Open seems like a sate but it's hard for me to conceptualize state in a stateless service. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service may be stateless, but many networking protocols are not.

From [Understanding State Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **State Machines and Channels**
>
> Objects that deal with communication, for
>   example sockets, usually present a state machine whose state
>   transitions relate to allocating network resources, making or
>   accepting connections, closing connections and terminating
>   communication. The channel state machine provides a uniform model of
>   the states of a communication object that abstracts the underlying
>   implementation of that object. The ICommunicationObject interface
>   provides a set of states, state transition methods and state
>   transition events. All channels, channel factories and channel
>   listeners implement the channel state machine.

The whole [WCF Channel Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729840%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good resource.